# Image Resizer: No image encoder was found for the request (WebP)

Tags: c#, imageresizer

I have a problem with the encoding of images in WebP format using the Imageresizer .NET library.

This is the fragment of code that raise the exception:

```
ImageResizer.ImageJob i1920Webp = new ImageResizer.ImageJob(filePath, filePath.Replace(name, name + "-1920").Replace(ext, ".webp"),new ImageResizer.Instructions("width=1920;format=webp;quality=65"));
i1920Webp.Build();
```

This is the relative stack trace:

```
[ImageProcessingException (0x80004005): No image encoder was found for this request.]
ImageResizer.ImageBuilder.buildToStream(Bitmap source, Stream dest, ResizeSettings settings) +270
ImageResizer.ImageBuilder.BuildJob(ImageJob job) +1237
ImageResizer.ImageBuilder.Build(ImageJob job) +268
```

The Build() method call raises the exception.
The destination file was created on filesystem but it's empty (0 byte); it's correctly named: image-1920.webp

I've installed the WebP plugin via NuGet; I've added the `<add name="WebPEncoder" />` in the plugins subsection of the resizer section of the web.config.

I don't understand what's the problem.

Comment: WebPEncoder isn't installed. Check the self-diagnostics page, `/resizer.debug` to see why.

Comment: I have this message:

`The following plugin assemblies are loaded but do not seem to be in use. You should remove them (and especially their dependencies (unless used elsewhere)) from the /bin folder to improve application load times:

ImageResizer.Plugins.WebP                Assembly: 3.4.3.103       File: 3.4.3.103`

Comment: Okay, then you need to correct your XML in web.config (assuming this is an ASP.NET app), or install the plugin via code (`new WebPEncoderPlugin().Install(Config.Current);`) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nathanael, I've followed the hints in your latest comment and now it works.
This is what I've done:

```
var config = new ImageResizer.Configuration.Config();
new WebPEncoderPlugin().Install(config);
config.BuildImage(
    filePath, 
    filePath.Replace(name, name + "-1920").Replace(ext, ".webp"),
    "width=1920;format=webp;quality=65"
);
```

Thank you for your support!